# Created copied Excel Worksheet throws 424 error

Tags: excel, vba

The goal is to create a copied sheet that is renamed in the current month and year. The copied sheet is being created in the workbook, however a default name is given to the sheet. What am I missing?

```
Private Sub Button3_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim nowMonth As Integer, nowYear As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

nowMonth = Month(Now)
nowYear = Year(Now)

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

On Error Resume Next

Set ws = wb.Sheet(nowMonth & ", " & nowYear)

On Error GoTo 0

If Not ws Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The Sheet called " & nowMonth & ", " & nowYear & " already exists in the workbook.", vbExclamation, "Sheet Already Exists!"
    Exit Sub

Else
    Set ws = ActiveSheet.Copy(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = nowMonth & ", " & nowYear

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `Set ws = ActiveSheet.Copy(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))`, because it is trying to `Copy` and `Set` in the same time and this is a bit too much.
Change the code in the condition to this:

```
If Not ws Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "something"
    Exit Sub
Else:
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Copy after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    wb.Worksheets(wb.Sheets.Count).Name = nowMonth & ", " & nowYear
End If
```

In general, avoid using `Active` and `Select` in VBA - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: `Copy` is creating (and activating) a new worksheet. OP's code means to set the `Name` of the new sheet - this code doesn't do that, it renames the copied sheet instead.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - and this is why `Activate` and `Select` should be avoided :) I have changed it.

Comment: Hm, why not just `Set newSheet = ActiveSheet` after the copy? The sheet ordering is dependent on the preceding line of code, so if that changes, the wrong sheet gets the new name.. ActiveSheet side-effect isn't ideal, but still better than repeating the ordering logic IMO.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - no idea. I am a bit "allergic" to `ActiveSheet`, but I left it only to make it easy for the the OP to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheet.Copy` disappointingly doesn't return a reference to the created sheet. Instead, it has the side-effect of adding a new sheet to the workbook, *and activating it*.

So after running `Worksheet.Copy`, the `ActiveSheet` is the newly created sheet.

```
ActiveSheet.Copy after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = nowMonth & ", " & nowYear
```

Now, this code is confusing/misleading, because it *looks* like the two statements are qualified with the same object, but they aren't.

What's not clear, is why and how the `ActiveSheet` is guaranteed to be the correct sheet to copy; we're working off the `ActiveWorkbook` and we don't really care which sheet is active.

I'd suggest to make the copy work off an explicit sheet:

```
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)

sourceSheet.Copy after:=sourceSheet '<~ new sheet becomes ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = nowMonth & ", " & nowYear
```

And now everything is as clear as it gets.